# I Don't get an object selecting an HTML element using jQuery in Safari 7.1 on MAC

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm trying to get the HTML content of an element using jQuery, works fine on each browsers I've tested such as Chrome Firefox Opera.. but with Safari 7.1 on MAC... it's not working I just get an Array containing the element.
So if I do that:

```
console.log($('#myElement').parent().find('svg').html());
```

I get this in my console.

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.innerHTML.replace')
```

Even if I do that it doesn't work:

```
console.log($($('#myElement').parent().find('svg').html()));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of this .....innerHTML.replace, use ....innerHTML = "new"

Comment: Ok so I explain.
I need to get the content of an svg element and store it to re append later. I do this:
$(this).parent().find('svg').html();
It works well on every other browsers.
But Safari on Mac .. it doesn't.
It is very annoying , especially That problem should be very easy to adjust .. certainly

Comment: hi, gays, I got the same problem with you. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

input is a singular or self-closing tag. I am not sure what are you trying get from this element. But if you are looking to check whether the checkbox is marked or not you can follow the following example 
[Example][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/
```

See, jquery object always returns an object on which any jquery method or handler can be applied.

I don't why its not woking for you. Anyhow, Try this

```
console.log($($('#checkbox')));
```

Comment: No the checkbox was an example.

Comment: All what I want is to get an object to apply method on my element selected with jQuery. like $('body').html("<div>insidebody</div>").. 
Whatever..

Comment: not working..
always the same return value..
an array containing the innerHTML.
Can not apply any method on it..

Comment: Have you tried this $($("#checkbox")). See, there are two dollar signs.

Comment: Bro, I think you are neglecting a very silly point.
Review your code and its execution again but before doing that have a glass of water and take some rest.

Comment: Yep your certainly right but The fact is that it works well in the other browsers.

Comment: Bro, I think you are neglecting a very silly point.
Review your code and its execution again but before doing that have a glass of water and take some rest.